# how scala treat companion object?

Tags: scala

I'm new to `Scala` with Java background.

In `java`  when we want to share any field among different objects of class. we declare that field `static`.

```
class Car {
 static NO_Of_TYRES = 4;
 // some implementation.
public int getCarNoOftyres(){
       NO_Of_TYRES; // although it's not a good practice to use static without class name
                    //but we can directly access static member in same class  . 
  }


}
```

But in Scala we cannot declare static fields in `class`, we need to use `object`(companion object) for that. 
In `scala` we will do like this,

```
class Car {
 println(NO_Of_TYRES); // scala doesn't let us do that. gives error 
 println(Car.NO_Of_TYRES);// this is correct way. 

}

object Car {
 val NO_Of_TYRES: Int = 4;
}
```

I'm just curious, how scala treat companion objects? 
what different these two key-words (`class and object`) makes ?
why does scala not letting us access `NO_Of_TYRES` directly in class?

Comment: You can `import Car._` either at the file level or inside the class and use `NO_OF_TYRES`

Comment: as per my knowledge, Companaion Object must be in same file? still i need to import i don't think so? 
my question is, how scala treats keyword class and object?

Comment: It needs to be in the same file.

Comment: I think the best answer for you is
https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179390/what-are-the-advantages-of-scalas-companion-objects-vs-static-methods
Please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to reference another answer about the same subject: [What are the advantages of Scala's companion objects vs static methods?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/179390/what-are-the-advantages-of-scalas-companion-objects-vs-static-methods)

See also **Section 4.3** of Odersky's book [Programming in Scala - Chapter 4 - Classes and Objects](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/classes-and-objects.html)

Scala treats everything as pure objects with their instances. In this view a java `static` member is not part of any instance, it lives a separate and different life.

With the tricks of the keyword `object` and some syntactic sugar, you can achieve the same result but maintaining the stated principle: a single instance of that object is instantiated and a global access point for the instance is provided.

Answer (score 3):

Companion objects are singleton class instances (and definitions), just to recall singleton in java is more or less:

```
class Foo {
    private Foo() { }
    /* boilerplate to prevent cloning */
    private static Foo instance = new Foo();
    public static Foo getInstance() { return instance; }

    public int bar() { return 5; }
}
```

and then to call method bar of this object:

```
Foo.getInstance().bar();
```

Scala removed all this boilerplate and lets you create equivalent thing with just

```
object Foo { 
    def bar: Int = 5 
}
```

and to call it you only need

```
Foo.bar
```

now what's the difference between 'object' and 'companion object'? It's actually quite simple - companion object (so the object defined in the same file as a class and having the same name) has access to it's related class private fields and methods, and that's probably why scala authors decided that it should reside in the same file - so that references to private fields are in the same file as their declarations (which I think is always the case both in Java and Scala, unless using reflection magic)

Comment: The most important reason is that you can always add new code to the system. If you were allowed to add a new companion object in a *different* compilation unit, then *anybody* could add a new companion object and break the class's encapsulation by accessing its privates. The requirement that both companions be in the same compilation unit ensures that encapsulation is preserved. Or, put another way: if you have access to the source file of the class, encapsulation is out the window anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Scala, as you pointed out, cannot have static variables or methods, as known in Java. Instead, there are singleton objects, which are declared with the keyword `object`. Calling a method in this objects is like calling a static method in Java, except you are calling the method on a singleton object instead.

If this object has the same name of a `class` or `trait`, it is called the companion object of the class/trait. A companion object must be defined inside the same source file as the class/trait.  A companion object differs from other objects as it has access rights to the related class/trait that other objects do not. In particular it can access methods and fields that are private in the class/trait.

Answer (score 1):

`Companion objects` provide us with a means to associate functionality with a class without associating it with any instance of that class. They are commonly used to provide additional constructors